# Cucumber: loop through steps within scenario

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I'm writing test using Java, Intellij, Selenium + Cucubmer.
I have a simple test scenario:

```
  Scenario: Add X random products to the shopping cart

      Given I choose a random product from a list
      When I add random quantity of the product to the shopping cart
      Then I see that number of products in the cart was updated
```

After last step I should go to first step and repeat all process X times. I don't know how to achieve it within one scenario without copying steps. Is it possible to run steps 1-3 in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this into a dummy `ScenarioOutline` like below and extend the examples table to whatever times you want.

```
  ScenarioOutline: Add X random products to the shopping cart

      Given I choose a random product from a list
      When I add random quantity of the product to the shopping cart
      Then I see that number of products in the cart was updated

    Examples:
    | id |
    | 1  |
    | 2  |
    | 3  |
```

Another way is to hack the runner code but this will only work for a single scenario you want repeated. [How to execute same cucumber feature or scenario n times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774655/how-to-execute-same-cucumber-feature-or-scenario-n-times/57776239#57776239)

Comment: I don't want to repeat whole scenario instead I would like to jump to step Given and start from there. Why is it so important within the the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following

```
Scenario: Add X random products to the shopping cart

      * configure retry = { count: <no-of-counts>, interval: <interval-between-each-retry-in-ms>}
      Given I choose a random product from a list
      And retry until <your-conditions>
      When I add random quantity of the product to the shopping cart
      Then I see that number of products in the cart was updated
```

Example:

```
Scenario: Add X random products to the shopping cart

      * configure retry = { count: X, interval: 0}
      Given I choose a random product from a list
      And retry until true
      When I add random quantity of the product to the shopping cart
      Then I see that number of products in the cart was updated
```

Here i have used count X as i have to add X random products and don't want to wait between them so the interval is 0 ms. I have also made the condition to be always true since i want to run for X without any conditions. You can write some condition like X==Y or X>Y or any other expression which results in a boolean value.

Comment: Can you show my an example how to define a condition?